# Await transaction using `go-ethereum/ethclient`

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, golang

In ethers.js, one can wait for a transaction to be mined with `wait()`. Is there a way to do this when using `ethclient` from `go-ethereum` as a package? I would like to wait for the result before moving on in the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [waitMined](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/afe344bcf31bfb477a6e1ad5b862a70fc5c1a22b/accounts/abi/bind/util.go#L32).

```golang
bind.WaitMined(context.Background(), client, signedTx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Created this function that polls the client for a transaction, returns a channel that only unblocks once the transaction is confirmed (and sends said transaction over the channel)

```go
// Returns a channel that blocks until the transaction is confirmed
func waitTxConfirmed(ctx context.Context, c *ethclient.Client, hash common.Hash) <-chan *types.Transaction {
    ch := make(chan *types.Transaction)
    go func() {
        for {
            tx, pending, _ := c.TransactionByHash(ctx, hash)
            if !pending {
                ch <- tx
            }

            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
        }
    }()

    return ch
}
```